# It is possible to store all types implementing a trait in a list and iterate over that list?

Tags: generics, types, rust

I have a trait implemented for many structs (`A`, `B`, `C`, etc.):

```rust
pub trait ApplicableFor: Debug + Default {
    unsafe fn is_applicable_for(from: *mut u8) -> bool
    where
        Self: Sized;
}
```

I need a method which finds which struct returns true for this method call. I have the code:

```rust
unsafe fn check_applicable<T: ApplicableFor>(from: *mut u8) -> bool {
    T::is_applicable_for(from, to)
}

unsafe fn find_applicable(from: *mut u8) -> ApplicableFor {
    if check_applicable::<A>(from) {
        A::default()
    } else if check_applicable::<B>(from) {
        B::default()
    } else if check_applicable::<C>(from) {
        C::default()
    } else {
        panic!("Couldn't find appicable");
    }
}
```

In the real code, I have around 20 structs, so I want to store them somewhere and use code like this for readability:

```
unsafe fn find_applicable(from: *mut u8) -> ApplicableFor {
    for T in list {
        if check_applicable::<T>(from) {
            T::default()
        }
    }
    panic!("Couldn't find appicable");
}
```

How can I do this or how can I rewrite this better?

Comment: Your code cannot compile, as `-> ApplicableFor` is invalid.

Comment: Also you call `T::is_applicable_for(from, to)` but it only has one argument: `is_applicable_for(from: *mut u8)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Rust does not directly offer the kind of metaprogramming features you need. Namely, a type is not a concrete thing that exists or can be put into a collection.

Instead, you need code generation.

Starting from a simplified version of `ApplicableFor`, we can write a very structured version of `find_applicable`:

```
trait ApplicableFor {
    fn is_applicable_for(from: u8) -> bool;
}

fn find_applicable(from: u8) {
    if <A>::is_applicable_for(from) {
        println!("Using {}", stringify!(A));
        return;
    }

    if <B>::is_applicable_for(from) {
        println!("Using {}", stringify!(B));
        return;
    }

    if <C>::is_applicable_for(from) {
        println!("Using {}", stringify!(C));
        return;
    }

    panic!("Couldn't find any applicable types");
}
```

Once we have established the structure, then we can start abstracting it with macros:

```
fn find_applicable(from: u8) {
    macro_rules! find_one {
        ($ty:ty) => {
            if <$ty>::is_applicable_for(from) {
                println!("Using {}", stringify!($ty));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    find_one!(A);
    find_one!(B);
    find_one!(C);

    panic!("Couldn't find any applicable types");
}
```

What if we want to repeat this concept of "do something for this list of types"? Another macro:

```
macro_rules! each_type {
    ($one_type_macro:tt) => {
        $one_type_macro!(A);
        $one_type_macro!(B);
        $one_type_macro!(C);
    };
}

fn find_applicable(from: u8) {
    macro_rules! find_one {
        ($ty:ty) => {
            if <$ty>::is_applicable_for(from) {
                println!("Using {}", stringify!($ty));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    each_type!(find_one);

    panic!("Couldn't find any applicable types");
}
```

Too much noise for the implementation of `each_type!`? Create a macro that creates another macro which will be called with another macro:

```
macro_rules! gen_each_type {
    ($($ty:ty),*) => {
        macro_rules! each_type {
            ($one_type_macro:tt) => {
                $($one_type_macro!($ty);)*
            };
        }
    };
}

gen_each_type![A, B, C];
```